# Using RegEx to split up a text into single words in Embarcadero's C++ Builder

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++builder

I am working on a spellchecker application with Embarcadero's C++ Builder. I split up a text into single words using a regular expression. The Code below worked fine with RAD Studio XE but does not behave in the same way with RAD Studio Seattle.

The problem appears when words contain non-latin characters like German Umlauts (Ä,Ö,Ü) or characters with accents (é,ê,à).
"\w" is interpreted as [a-zA-Z_0-9] ignoring non-latin characters.

First, what is a word in my context?
Possible words consist of:

- "\r\n"
- "word-word-word-word ..."
- "word." or "word-"
- words with apostrophs: " 'word" "wor'd" "word' "
- "word"
- there are two different types of apostrophes: ' and ’

Here's the Code:

```
String text (L"Österreich l'année);
const String sRegex (L"\r\n|(\\w+\\-)+\\w+|\\w+(\\.|\\-)|('|’)?\\w+('|’)?\\w*");
TRegEx regex(sRegex, TRegExOptions());
TMatchCollection regexMatches = regex.Matches(text);
for (int i=0; i<regexMatches.Count; ++i)
{
    TMatch regexMatch = regexMatches.Item[i];
    String word (regexMatch.Value);

    //do stuff with word
}
```

The desired values for the String word are "Österreich" and "l'année". However, what the RegEx matches is "sterreich", "l'ann" and "e".

My question is, how to specify all non-latin characters?

Comment: Don't know if you flavor supports it, but maybe you could work from `[\p{L}']*`. [See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jU0rV7/1).

Comment: Make small test: if your regex flavor is PCRE, add `(*UTF)(*UCP)` at the pattern beginning. If that does not work, you might be dealing with JS ECMAScript 5 regex flavor that is not Unicode aware.

Comment: Thanks, using \p{L} instead of \w worked!

Comment: @AndreasS.: `\p{L}` matches only letters. Your regex contains `\w`. It is more reasonable just to make your regex pattern Unicode aware. Did you try `L"(*UTF)(*UCP)\r\n|(\\w+\\-)+\\w+|\\w+(\\.|\\-)|('|’)?\\w+('|’)?\\w*"`? Or a much better one - `L"(*UTF)(*UCP)\r\n|(\\w+-)+\\w+|\\w+[.-]|['’]?\\w+['’]?\\w*"`?

Comment: Hm, (*UTF) und (*UCP) both produce a RegularExpressionError exception saying  '(*VERB) not recognized'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p{L}` matches a *unicode letter*. Try using that instead of `\w`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jU0rV7/1).

If you want digits as well (as with `\w`) add `\d` to the group.

Comment: And to avoid the comments ;) - by *unicode letter* I mean a unicode code point in the letter category. *unicode letter* simplifies the answer though (imo).

Comment: Just to add to it: `\p{L}` only matches a base letter, if diacritics need to be matched, too, add `\p{M}` - `[\p{L}\p{M}]`. A digit class can also be added (since the original had `\w` that includes digits).